# Deleting last node from Firebase Realtime Database via REST API

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

My Firebase Realtime Database looks like this:

[image: Database]

I want to delete last node `-M8VOQO11nYo8iMC6NZ_` from it.
In the official document of Firebase REST API the CURL code to delete it is `curl -X DELETE \
  'https://[PROJECT_ID].firebaseio.com/Texter.json'`
 but it deletes the entire branch. Is there a way to delete only the last node?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only write/delete a node if you knows its entire path. So to delete the last child node, you need to take two steps:

1. Use a [query in a `GET` call](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/retrieve-data#section-rest-filtering) to determine the key of the last child node
2. Use `DELETE` call to then delete that path.

The query would look something like:

```
https://[PROJECT_ID].firebaseio.com/Texter.json?orderBy="$key"&limitToLast=1
```

Comment: Thanks @frank-van-puffelen, but it didn't work. In Python3 `requests.delete('https://[PROJECT_ID].firebaseio.com/Texter.json?orderBy="$key"&limitToLast=1')` gives `<Response [400]>` error.

Comment: You need two do a multi-step process: 1) use a **`GET`** call to execute a query to determine the key of the last node, 2) loop over the results, 3) call `DELETE` for each key (which will be only one here, but you still need the loop). You're trying to combine all steps into one call, which doesn't work because Firebase doesn't support update/delete queries.

Answer (score 0):

I found this solution:

Endpoint to fetch last node

```
url = https://[PROJECT_ID].firebaseio.com/Texter.json?orderBy="$key"&limitToLast=1
```

Fetching response

```
response= requests.get(url)
```

Extracting last node index from response

```
last_node = list(response.json().keys())[0]
```

Delete endpoint with that node

```
del_url = f'https://[PROJECT_ID].firebaseio.com/Texter/{last_node}.json'
```

Calling delete with that node index in endpoint

```
del_res = requests.delete(del_url)
```